# Will --vout=dummy option work with --video-filter=scene?

Tags: libvlc, libvlcsharp

I am trying to create snapshots from a video stream using the "scene" video filter. I'm on Windows for now, but this will run on Linux I don't want the video output window to display.  I can get the scenes to generate if I don't use the --vout=dummy option.  When I include that option, it does not generate the scenes.

[This example on the Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Make_thumbnails/) indicates that it's possible. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the line of code from the LibVLCSharp code:

```
LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC("--no-audio", "--no-spu", "--vout=dummy", "--video-filter=scene", "--scene-format=jpeg", "--scene-prefix=snap", "--scene-path=C:\\temp\\", "--scene-ratio=100", $"--rtsp-user={rtspUser}", $"--rtsp-pwd={rtspPassword}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VLC 3, you will need to disable hardware acceleration which seems incompatible with the dummy vout.

In my tests, it was needed to do that on the media rather than globally:

```cs
media.AddOption(":avcodec-hw=none");
```

I still have mainy "Too high level or recursion" errors, and for that, I guess you'd better open an issue on videolan's trac.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well!  Thanks @cube45!!